# How to do additional processing in Java Stream API near the "::" method reference operator

Tags: java, java-stream

Using the Java Stream API, is there a way to do additional processing to adjust the value of whatever is passed to a method reference?

I'll give two examples.

**Example 1.**

In the first example, I start with a `Stream<Path>`, and I want to return a `Map<String, Path>` in which the keys in the map are processed version of the filename using another function that takes a `String` filename (not a `Path`). Specifically:

```
public Map<String, Path> createMap(Path sourceFolder, PathMatcher filter) {
    return stream.filter(filter::matches)
                 .collect(Collectors.toMap(FilenameHelper::parseFilename, Function.identity()));
```

`parseFilename(String filename)` takes a String filename, but of course the method reference gets a Path. I'd like to say something like, `FilenameHelper::parseFilename(((Path)Function.identity()).toFile().getName())` but that doesn't work (Eclipse says: "The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable"). I can work around it by creating a new method that takes a `Path` and just does `return parseFilename(path.toFile().toName())` but that's not cool.

**Example 2.**

In the second example, I have `rows`, a `List<List<String>>>` that represents a data table (rows, then columns). I have a method that should return a `List<String>` consisting of a specific column in that table for every nth row. I want to do something like:

```
public List<String> getDataFromColumn(String columnName, int nth) {
    /// Without a clause at ???, this returns a List<List<String>>
    return IntStream.range(0, rows.size())     
                    .filter(n -> n % nth == 0) // Get every nth row
                    .mapToObj(rows::get)       
                    .???
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Where "???" should be something like `map(ArrayList::get(headers.indexOf(columnName)))` (where `headers` is a `List<String>` containing the column headers) but if I put that in, I get an `AssignmentOperator` syntax error in the `get` part of this clause. Replacing `map` with `forEach` doesn't help here. In other words, I don't want `rows.get(n)`, I want `rows.get(n).get(headers.indexOf(columnName)`.

**Question**

In both of these examples, I want to do something additional to the value that is being passed to the method pointed to with the method reference operator (`::`). **Is there a "Java Stream-ic" way to do additional processing to the thing being passed to the method reference?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Method references are essentially a convenient substitute for lambdas where the function signature is an exact match to the method signature. In your case you can just use regular lambdas:

```
public Map<String, Path> createMap(Path sourceFolder, PathMatcher filter) {
    return stream.filter(filter::matches)
                 .collect(Collectors.toMap(path -> FilenameHelper.parseFilename(path.toFile().getName()), Function.identity()));
}
```

```
public List<String> getDataFromColumn(String columnName, int nth) {
    return IntStream.range(0, rows.size())
                    .filter(n -> n % nth == 0)
                    .mapToObj(rows::get)
                    .map(row -> row.get(headers.indexOf(columnName)))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: In the first case, I'm getting an error that the result seems to be a Map<Object, Path> instead of Map<String, Path>, even though the return value of parseFilename is String. I'll keep hammering away at this, unless there's something that comes quickly to your mind about why that might be the case.

Comment: @DavidKoelle It works for me with a `Stream<Path>`. Might be a bug in your compiler version. I know at one point Eclipse had a lot of type inference bugs in Java 8.

Answer (score 4):

How about `Function.compose`? Of course you cannot use `FilenameHelper::parseFilename.compose`, but you can easily write a static helper method to work around it:

```
static <T, V, R> Function<T, R> compose(Function<T, V> f, Function<V, R> g) {
    return g.compose(f);
}
```

Now we can compose method references:

```
return stream.filter(filter::matches)
         .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                  compose(
                      compose(Path::getFileName, Path::toString), 
                      FilenameHelper::parseFilename),
                  Function.identity()));
```

This is actually not very readable but an alternative to writing a full lambda.

Comment: brilliant and made us all look like fools(in a good and constructive way). +1! we all jumped that there is no way to do unless with a lambda, but your advise is much better IMHO

Comment: @Eugene I don't think this is better at all. But it has my upvote because it is an alternative that directly answers the question.

Comment: Thanks for the upvotes, guys. I don't think it's better either, just an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

No, this functionality is currently not provided.

The usual way would be to just not use a method reference and instead call the method the "usual" way using a lambda expression:

```
stream.filter(filter::matches)
             .collect(Collectors.toMap(p -> FilenameHelper.parseFilename(p.getFileName()), Function.identity()));
```

Answer (score 1):

No, there is not. There is no syntax to do that.
And if you wanted such a thing then lambda expression is what you want.

Method reference or lambda, under the hood you are still going to get a class that actually implements the Predicate/Function so it does not matter.

And that argument *but that's not cool*, to me under the conditions that there is no syntax for that, it's the best option you have.

Underneath the actual calls that you there is a MethodHandle (introduced in jdk-7) and MethodHandles do not have a way to achieve what you want. I think the same restriction exists in C++ with method pointers.